# How to type a variable for a Prisma select property

Tags: typescript, prisma

I’m looking for a way to define a Prisma select statement and then use it in multiple places. For example:

```
const userSelect: Prisma.UserSelect = {
    id: true,
    name: true,
}

const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: { id: 1 },
    select: userSelect
})

const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: { authorId: 1 },
    select: {
        id: true,
        user: {
            select: userSelect
        }
    }
})
```

However, this isn’t working properly. When using `userSelect` in the queries, the queries know `userSelect` is of the expected type `Prisma.UserSelect`, but they don’t know which fields have actually been selected. This ends up typing both `user` and `posts.user` to be `{}`.

A different approach would be to instead write `userSelect` like this:

```
const userSelect = {
    id: true,
    name: true,
} as const;
```

That works in the query and correctly types the query result. However, now I lose type safety and autocomplete in the definition of `userSelect`.

Can someone think of a solution that would work correctly in the query select property, the query result, and that would also allow type safety in the definition of the select object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TS 4.9+, you would use `satisfies` for this:

```
const userSelect = { ... } satisfies Prisma.UserSelect;
```

This maintains the type of `userSelect` while still checking and autocompleting inside the brackets.

The canonical solution to this problem in TS 4.8 is to use a generic helper function:

```
function makeUserSelect<T extends Prisma.UserSelect>(t: T): T { return t; }

const userSelect = makeUserSelect({ ... });
```

Answer (score 10):

An article covering this exact topic was just released by Prisma.
https://www.prisma.io/blog/satisfies-operator-ur8ys8ccq7zb

To quote from the article:

> One of the most common use cases for the satisfies operator with
> Prisma is to infer the return type of a specific query method like a
> findUnique — including only the selected fields of a model and its
> relations.

```js
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

// Create a strongly typed `PostSelect` object with `satisfies`
const postSelect = {
  title: true,
  createdAt: true,
  author: {
    name: true,
    email: true,
  },
} satisfies Prisma.PostSelect;

// Infer the resulting payload type
type MyPostPayload = Prisma.PostGetPayload<{ select: typeof postSelect }>;

// The result type is equivalent to `MyPostPayload | null`
const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
  where: { id: 3 },
  select: postSelect,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
export const userSelect = {
    id: true,
    name: true,
}

export type UserSelect = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{ select: typeof useSelect }>
```

```js
const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: { authorId: 1 },
    select: {
        id: true,
        user: {
            select: userSelect
        }
    }
})
```

should be properly typed and you can use `UserSelect` type where necessary.